# How to render an array of objects in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

could you please tell me how to render a list in react js.
I do like this

https://plnkr.co/edit/X9Ov5roJtTSk9YhqYUdp?p=preview

```
class First extends React.Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props);

  }

  render() {
     const data =[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"}];
    const listItems = data.map((d) => <li key={d.name}>{d.name}</li>;
    
    return (
      <div>
      hello
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i googled and found many articles such as this: http://jasonjl.me/blog/2015/04/18/rendering-list-of-elements-in-react-with-jsx/

Comment: hmm... your shared plnkr app isn't functional for me..

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

**First:**

```
render() {
    const data =[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"}];
    const listItems = data.map((d) => <li key={d.name}>{d.name}</li>);

    return (
      <div>
      {listItems }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**Second:** Directly write the map function in the return

```
render() {
    const data =[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"}];
    return (
      <div>
      {data.map(function(d, idx){
         return (<li key={idx}>{d.name}</li>)
       })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: pls share plunker

Comment: Yeah working on it, you havn't included babel in your plunker

Comment: pls let me know how to include babel in plunker

Comment: here is a working plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/kFKBi8qUAC02eeHOYUB3?p=preview

No need to include babel in plnkr it seems

Comment: what are the changes you did ?

Comment: Instead of using the arrow function, I made use of the normal function

Comment: Don't use idx (index of loop) as key property of JSX element to avoid issues. Read this https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys. Instead idx make use of some `d.id`.

Comment: As Enrique René mentioned array index should be avoided, however as the data is already an array of object and assuming keys are unique(name) so name1, name2 etc, would be good to use them as in the first example

Answer (score 21):

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions

> You can pass any JavaScript expression as children, by enclosing it within {}. For example, these expressions are equivalent:
>
> ```
> <MyComponent>foo</MyComponent>
>
> <MyComponent>{'foo'}</MyComponent>
> ```
>
> This is often useful for rendering a list of JSX expressions of arbitrary length. For example, this renders an HTML list:
>
> ```
> function Item(props) {
>   return <li>{props.message}</li>;
> }
>
> function TodoList() {
>   const todos = ['finish doc', 'submit pr', 'nag dan to review'];
>   return (
>     <ul>
>       {todos.map((message) => <Item key={message} message={message} />)}
>     </ul>
>   );
> }
> ```

---

```js
class First extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [{name: 'bob'}, {name: 'chris'}],
    };
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.data.map(d => <li key={d.name}>{d.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <First />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Shubham's answer explains very well. This answer is addition to it as per to avoid some pitfalls and refactoring to a more readable syntax

**Pitfall** : There is common misconception in rendering array of objects especially if there is an update or delete action performed on data. Use case would be like deleting an item from table row. Sometimes when row which is expected to be deleted, does not get deleted and instead other row gets deleted.

To **avoid** this, use `key` prop in  root element which is looped over in JSX tree of `.map()`. Also adding React's `Fragment` will avoid adding another element in between of `ul` and `li` when rendered via calling method.

```
state = {
    userData: [
        { id: '1', name: 'Joe', user_type: 'Developer' },
        { id: '2', name: 'Hill', user_type: 'Designer' }
    ]
};

deleteUser = id => {
    // delete operation to remove item
};

renderItems = () => {
    const data = this.state.userData;

    const mapRows = data.map((item, index) => (
        <Fragment key={item.id}>
            <li>
                {/* Passing unique value to 'key' prop, eases process for virtual DOM to remove specific element and update HTML tree  */}
                <span>Name : {item.name}</span>
                <span>User Type: {item.user_type}</span>
                <button onClick={() => this.deleteUser(item.id)}>
                    Delete User
                </button>
            </li>
        </Fragment>
    ));
    return mapRows;
};

render() {
    return <ul>{this.renderItems()}</ul>;
}
```

**Important** : Decision to use which value should we pass to `key` prop also matters as common way is to use `index` parameter provided by `.map()`.

TLDR; But there's a drawback to it and avoid it as much as possible and use any unique `id` from data which is being iterated such as `item.id`. There's a good article on this - https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: Why not just put the key in the <li> element rather than wrapping in a <fragment>?

Comment: You can do that as well. I've added Fragment because it's like my practice and Fragment does very good merging of DOM elements ensuring that no other element is being placed while rendering via mapped data.

Answer (score 3):

Try this below code in app.js file, easy to understand

```
function List({}) {
  var nameList = [
    { id: "01", firstname: "Rahul", lastname: "Gulati" },
    { id: "02", firstname: "Ronak", lastname: "Gupta" },
    { id: "03", firstname: "Vaishali", lastname: "Kohli" },
    { id: "04", firstname: "Peter", lastname: "Sharma" }
  ];
  const itemList = nameList.map((item) => (
    <li>
      {item.firstname} {item.lastname}
    </li>
  ));
  return (
    <div>
      <ol style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>{itemList}</ol>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <List />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from 'react';

class RentalHome extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            rentals:[{
                _id: 1,
                title: "Nice Shahghouse Biryani",
                city: "Hyderabad",
                category: "condo",
                image: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x250",
                numOfRooms: 4,
                shared: true,
                description: "Very nice apartment in center of the city.",
                dailyPrice: 43
              },
              {
                _id: 2,
                title: "Modern apartment in center",
                city: "Bangalore",
                category: "apartment",
                image: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x250",
                numOfRooms: 1,
                shared: false,
                description: "Very nice apartment in center of the city.",
                dailyPrice: 11
              },
              {
                _id: 3,
                title: "Old house in nature",
                city: "Patna",
                category: "house",
                image: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x250",
                numOfRooms: 5,
                shared: true,
                description: "Very nice apartment in center of the city.",
                dailyPrice: 23
              }]
        }
    }
    render(){
        const {rentals} = this.state;
        return(
            <div className="card-list">
                <div className="container">
                    <h1 className="page-title">Your Home All Around the World</h1>
                    <div className="row">
                        {
                            rentals.map((rental)=>{
                                return(
                                    <div key={rental._id} className="col-md-3">
                                        <div className="card bwm-card">
                                        <img 
                                        className="card-img-top" 
                                        src={rental.image}
                                        alt={rental.title} />
                                        <div className="card-body">
                                        <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-0 text-muted">
                                            {rental.shared} {rental.category} {rental.city}
                                        </h6>
                                        <h5 className="card-title big-font">
                                            {rental.title}
                                        </h5>
                                        <p className="card-text">
                                            ${rental.dailyPrice} per Night &#183; Free Cancelation
                                        </p>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default RentalHome;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
class First extends React.Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props);

  }

  render() {
     const data =[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"}];
    const listItems = data.map((d) => <li key={d.name}>{d.name}</li>;
    
    return (
      <div>
      {listItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```