# Rendering React Components from Array of Objects in state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, menu

I have a object like this in my `this.state.data` :

```
{
  "companies": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "description": "Fernando"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "description": "Paulo"
    }
  ]
}
```

I get this object from a get method in a url and set him in my `this.state.data`.
I want to render my menu with options that are the descriptions of the array, like this :

```
 <MenuItem value={10} >Fernando</MenuItem>
 <MenuItem value={20}>Paulo</MenuItem>
```

But i want to make it render dynamiclly, sometimes i will recieve a array with 10 id's and descriptions, so i need to render 10 options in the menu.
I already try to map the object, but i'm still stuck at this.

PS: I'm setting the content on a state because i can change it anytime.

Comment: Where's the code showing your attempt at using map?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render an array of objects in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41374572/how-to-render-an-array-of-objects-in-react)

Comment: Also see https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you just wanting the `description` to be dynamically added?

You can do

```
this.state.data.companies.map(company => (
   <MenuItem key={company.id}>{company.description}</MenuItem>
))
```

This will return a MenuItem for each item in the array

I'm not sure what you need for the `value` prop but that can be dynamically changed in the same manner

Comment: i do this in the render method?

Comment: You can, if you wrap it with `{ }`, or you could write a function that does it, and call the function in the render method.

`<Menu>{this.generateMenuItems()</Menu>`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the render method,

```
{this.state.data.companies.map((company) => {
   <MenuItem id={company.id} key={company.id} description={company.description}/>
})}
```

Then use the company description inside the MenuItem component as this.props.description