# State in react is not rendering to the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i created an `state` in constructor, and `setState` in `componentDidmount`, when i try to `render` that state object to screen, it is throwing error, server im using is `node API`, and every other things are working fine. help me to solve this issue

app.js (react)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.State = {
      messages:[]
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/patient/billing_get')
      .then((result) => {
        const messages = result.data
        console.log(messages);
        this.setState({
          messages: [...messages]
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          <div>{this.State}</div>
         </p>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

route function which im calling from node API:

```
function billing_get(req,res) {
    res.send("get method working")
}
```

Note : i have created this project by modifying `create-react-app`, and i have added `proxy` under react package.json to establish connection between node API and react

complete error message:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {messages}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in div (at App.js:42)
    in p (at App.js:40)
    in div (at App.js:35)
    in App (at index.js:7)
./src/index.js
src/index.js:7

   4 | import App from './App';
   5 | import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
   8 | registerServiceWorker();
   9 | 
  10 | 

This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
```

Comment: looks like you are doing this.State instead of this.state .. also you can't print it like that cuz it's an object, print it like {this.state.messages[0].id} for example

Comment: What part of that error message don't you understand? Looks pretty clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: why do you have `State` and not `state` ?

Comment: @Dario tried both state and State, shows me same error

Comment: @ShahafAntwarg not working

Comment: @James im beginner, if you understand what the error is, explain me please

Comment: Actually, error message shows everything you need. Objects are not valid as a React child. You try to write your state as React child and it is wrong. Artem's and vapurrmaid's answers seems true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render an array of objects in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41374572/how-to-render-an-array-of-objects-in-react/41374730#41374730)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first rename `this.State` to `this.state`, state definition should be lowercase.

In app component you render object in `<div />` jsx elemnt, it is incorrect. Try to map your messages and return separate element for each entity:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.State = {
      messages:[]
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/patient/billing_get')
      .then((result) => {
        const messages = result.data
        console.log(messages);
        this.setState({
          messages: [...messages]
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
   const { messages }  = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          <div>
           {messages.map(item => <span key={messages.indexOf(item)}>{item}</span>)}
          </div>
         </p>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

## Edit validate html

```
render() {
   const { messages }  = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <div className="App-intro">
          <p>To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.</p>
          <div>
           {messages.map(item => <span key={messages.indexOf(item)}>{item}</span>)}
          </div>
         </div>
     </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, still getting this error when using your code,      Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.
    in div (at App.js:34)
    in p (at App.js:32)
    in div (at App.js:27)
    in App (at index.js:7)

Comment: This error occurs because html nesting invalid. I edit my answer to make it valid in your render method.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot render the `state` object (**note: lowercase**, not `State`!), the following will never work:

```
<div>{this.state}</div>
```

Instead, pull off properties like the following:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      messages: ['hi', 'bye']
    }
  }
  
  render () {
    // pull off messages array from state, then map over it to get each message
    const { messages } = this.state 
    return (
      <div>
        {messages.map(message => (
          <div>{message}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <Example />, 
 document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<div id='root'></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Afternoon m8,

Change `State` to `state` and then in your render function change 
`<div>{this.State}</div>` to `<div>{this.state.messages}</div>` 
or change to the following to have more control on how to render each message.

```
 <div>
  {
      this.state.messages.map((message) => {
           return (<div>{message}</div>);
      })
  }
 </div>
```

Also you need to change how you're updating the state in the axios callback, change this

```
axios.get('/patient/billing_get')
  .then((result) => {
    const messages = result.data
    console.log(messages);
    this.setState({
      messages: [...messages]
    })
})
```

To this

```
axios.get('/patient/billing_get')
  .then((result) => {
    // Because you're just returning a string and not an array..
    const message = result.data
    this.setState({
      messages: [...this.state.messages, messages]
    })
})
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, still getting this error when using your code, Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>. in div (at App.js:34) in p (at App.js:32) in div (at App.js:27) in App (at index.js:7)

Comment: @FunWorld updated my answer to fix it for you. also, change your div tags on line 32 to a span tag.. looks like you've got linting.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply :)