# Parsing JSON object in reactjs

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs and trying to build a basic ui by parsing a json object.

```
class App extends Component {

  state ={
    products : []
  };
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit = {this.addNewProducts}/>
        <ProductList products = {this.state.products} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const ProductList =(props) => {

  return(
    <div>
      {props.products.map(product => <Product {...product}/>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Trying to render some of the data from json here, which is where I'm struggling with. Tried to use Map but no luck, at least I'm not using it correctly.

```
const Product = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <div>
        {props.pludetails}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Returning JSON object:

```
{
    "ResultCode": 0,
    "ResultDescription": "Success",
    "pludetails": [
        {
            "UPC": 490000129,
            "ItemDesc": "SPRITE",
            "Department": 197,
            "Price1": 7.99,
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You are trying to display object. You can’t do something like that html accept only string this mean you need to try to display property instead of object

Comment: pludetails is also an array of object, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41374572/how-to-render-an-array-of-objects-in-react/41374730#41374730

Comment: Yes, I was getting errors for displaying object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you just render js object as React child, but you need to write render function for `pludetails`.

Here is short example:

```
const Pludetails = (props) => {
 return(
   <div>
    <span>{props.UPC}</span>
    <span>{props.ItemDesc}</span>
    <span>{props.Department}</span>
    <span>{props.Price1}</span> 
   </div>
 );
}
```

In `Product` :

```
const Product = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <div>
        {props.pludetails.map((item, i) => <Pludetails key={i} {...item}/>)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In `ProductList` add key prop, for reduce `key` errors:

```
const ProductList =(props) => {

  return(
    <div>
      {props.products.map((product, i) => <Product key={i} {...product}/>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Use indexes by keys width dynamic data is danger. You can use `id` or something else what you wont.

Comment: Thanks Artem. That did the trick. Good learning for me to handle the multi-level json.