# Updating state from another component in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update the state of a main component from the "A" component then push it to "B" component and then use it render to dynamically populate boxes.

**Main Component :**

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            events:[],
            alerts:[],
        };

      }
  addEvent = newEvent => this.setState(state => {
    const {events} = this.state
    return [...events, newEvent]
  });

  addAlert = newAlert => this.setState(state =>{
    const {alerts} = this.state
    return [...alerts, newAlert]
  });

render(){
    const {events} = this.state
    const {alerts} = this.state
    console.log(events) // events are empty even after I pass and store it 
                        //   in SearchFlight Component  
    return(
        <div >

                <SearchFlight events={events} alerts={alerts} addAlert={this.addAlert} addEvent={this.addEvent} />
                <Events events={events}/>
                <Alerts />
            </div>

    );

}
```

**SearchFlight Component(A component) :**

```
handleSubmit= event =>{
        const {addEvent} = this.props
        const {addAlert} = this.props
        event.preventDefault();

        var newEvents=[];
        var newAlerts=[];


                 var singleEvent={
                   event_name:'home',
                   date_time:'12-08-18 12:45 AM',
                 };

                  newEvents.push(singleEvent);

                  newAlerts.push("Remove the luggage tag");

           addAlert(newAlerts);  
           addEvent(newEvents);

    }
```

Then I have **Event Component(B Component)** which right now just have render method. I want to get the updated events here.

**Problem** : Getting empty events when I did `console.log(events)` in render method of **Main Component**

Comment: did you use this.props.events in Events Component

Comment: yes I did got nothing because it's not updated right? I updated the state in A component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the setState correctly in `addEvents` and `addAlerts` method. the callback pattern of setState needs to return an object

```
addEvent = newEvent => this.setState(state => {
    const {events} = state
    return { events: [...events, ...newEvent]}
  });

  addAlert = newAlert => this.setState(state =>{
    const {alerts} = state
    return {alerts: [...alerts, ...newAlert]
  });
```

Also since events is an array of objects your need to iterate on them to render. Refer [How to render an array of objects in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41374572/how-to-render-an-array-of-objects-in-react/41374730#41374730) answer for more details on how to do that

Comment: In console I got my events in Main Component but when I did `this.props.events` to receive it since I am passing props from Main Component `<Event events={events}/>` . I received this error **Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {event_name, date_time}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array**

Comment: I received this error when again I passed events to B component

Comment: How are you rendering the events in component B. The errors seems to be related to that

Comment: this way `<div>{this.props.events}</div>` but since events is jsonarray therefore that's why I am getting the error I might need to iterate can you post on that?

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: Perfect! Lastly if I want to format the values I received how will I loop inside a div

because I want boxes like feature

event_name(key1) as a button then next line date_time(key2)

Comment: You would loop over the events array which gives you an event object. Now you can choose to render each property as you want like `<div><div>{event.event_name}</div><button>{event.id}</button></div>`

Comment: I am not able to empty this list like it is appending again and again

Comment: Please ask another question with the details about your current problem. Comments will get too messy discussing an unrelated issue here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53555834/empty-the-state-of-parent-component-from-button-in-child-component

Answer (score 1):

The State is private to the component.
If the state is passed to the child component using props, again props should not be mutated as per the reactjs guidelines.

You can only read the value in Component A from the props and modify that value to pass it further to the nested components. But can't modify the state of the Main Component from A.

Check this out: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: The way OP is attempting to update the state of Main component from `SearchFlight` is correct

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by OneJeet React is all about top-down approach and the child component should not be aware if a parent component is stateless or stateful.

Passing the setState as a function and allowing the child component to call it, is bad practice. One way is to use redux and eliminate the need to update parent state from child component or re-structure the whole thing in a different way.