# Empty the state of parent component from button in child component

Tags: reactjs

I want to clear the state of child from previous state after I click a button again from child component.

**Parent Component**

```
   constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                events:[],
                alerts:[],
            };

          }


addEvent = newEvent => this.setState(state => {
    const {events} = state
    return { events: [...events, ...newEvent]}
  });

  addAlert = newAlert => this.setState(state =>{
    const {alerts} = state
    return {alerts: [...alerts, ...newAlert]
  });

 render(){

    const {events} = this.state
            const {alerts} = this.state
            console.log(alerts);
            return(
                <div >
                    <SearchFlight events={events} alerts={alerts} addAlert={this.addAlert} addEvent={this.addEvent} />

                        <Events events={events}/>
                        <Alerts alerts={alerts}/>

}
```

**Child Component**

```
handleSubmit= event =>{
        const {addEvent} = this.props
        const {addAlert} = this.props
        event.preventDefault();
        //alert(this.state.search_flight_no);
        var airportValueSelected= this.state.airport;
        var flightValue= this.state.search_flight_no;
        var airportList= FlightInfo.Airport;
        var newEvents=[];
        var newAlerts=[];
        for(var rootKey in airportList){
          if(rootKey===airportValueSelected)
           {

               airportList[rootKey].forEach(element => {


                   if(element.flight_no===flightValue){

                    for(var m=0;m<element.Events.length;m++){

                     var singleEvent={
                       event_name:'',
                       date_time:'',
                     };

                      singleEvent.event_name=element.Events[m].event_name;
                      singleEvent.date_time=element.Events[m].date_time;
                      newEvents.push(singleEvent);
                    }

                    for(var s=0;s<element.Alerts.length;s++){

                      newAlerts.push(element.Alerts[s]["Alert"+(s+1)]);

                    }

                   }

               });
               if(newEvents.length<1 && newAlerts.length<1){
                this.setState({ open: true });
               }
               else{
                 console.log(newEvents);
                 console.log(newAlerts);
               }
               addAlert(newAlerts);  
               addEvent(newEvents);

           }
        }
```

When I click and call **handleSubmit** method it keeps on appending events and alerts rather making it **empty** and storing new values rather **appending** previous state values.

Comment: Do you mean to update the events prop with only the currently submitted values??

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that addEvents and addAlerts is appending the values is because you are just setting the current value in state, but appending them in the setState call with spread syntax. You just need to write

```
addEvent = newEvent => this.setState({
    events: newEvent
  });

  addAlert = newAlert => this.setState({
      alerts: newAlert
  });
```

Comment: Working but you haven't told how to format `const eachEventName= this.props.events.map((d) => <li key={d.event_name}>{d.event_name}</li>)
        const eachDateTime= this.props.events.map((d) => <li key={d.date_time}>{d.date_time}</li>)
        return(
            <div>
             {eachEventName}   
             {eachDateTime}
            </div>
        );`

Actually I want button with text event_name then below that date_time

Comment: You would simply do `this.props.events.map((event) => { <ul key={event.event_name}><li>{d.event_name}</li><li>{d.date_time}</li></ul>})`

Comment: Expected an assignment or function instead an saw expression in `<ul></ul>`

Comment: the right way would be `{this.props.events.map((event) =>  
               ( <ul key={event.event_name}><li>{event.event_name}</li><li>{event.date_time}</li></ul>
            ))}`

Comment: yeah, was a typo in comment

Comment: Please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627141/remove-previous-events-from-state-object-in-reactjs