# Remove previous events from state Object in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button Mic-off and Mic-on which is a toggle achieved using ternary operation. `events`(JSON array) is a list of JSON Object with `event_name` and `date_time`.

```
{this.props.events.map((event) => (
 <div  key={event.event_name}>
    <div> {this.state.micStates[event.event_name]?
     <span onClick={()=>this.stopRecord(event.event_name)}> <MicOn /> 
     </span> 
     :<span onClick={()=>this.startRecord(event.event_name)}><MicOff />       
    </span>}              
   </div>
   <li style={{color:'pink',}}>{event.date_time}</li>
 </div> ))
}
```

**Two methods**: ***startRecord, StopRecord***

**startRecord**: It will start the recording and store in chunks and remove previous event state either set it to false if clicked more than once

**stopRecord**: It will stop the mediaRecorder and save the file in formData
and set current state event to false.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        mics :{},
    }
}
startRecord = event => {
    var size=Object.keys(this.state.mics).length
    if(size<1){
        let {mics}=this.state;
        mics[event]=mics[event]? false : true;
        this.setState({ mics });


        // do the work here
    }
    else{
        this.setState(prevState=>({
            mics:{},
        }));
        console.log("switch other state off");
    }
}

stopRecord = event => {

    let {mics}=this.state;
    mics[event]=mics[event]? false : true;
    this.setState({ mics });
    console.log(Object.keys(this.state.mics).length);

}
```

I don't want to switch multiple button at one time if one event is true then other present in `mics` should in false.

Comment: store an active event id, for instance if you start_record on one event which `id: 123` then active id will be `123` and for only this id you can take the customn action

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I have already passed unique key to both method if you look

Though I have done and  issue is resolved and it's working but not as I wanted updated my code **if and else condition**.....what I want is if I make `mics[event]` true for one by clicking current event then the previous mics[event] should become false means the only difference I am facing right now is if I click another event all the mics state are empty therefore will be switched off rather it should be false for previous

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri the question is how do I access the previous object element in else condition then I could easily set it false and let the current which I am passing be true only......

Comment: You maintain the mics object, instead what I would suggest is to keep a single variable if that works for you.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri that is because I used ternary operation for each unique element `this.state.mics[event]` there need to have object

Answer (score 0):

As this.state.micStates is an array. Keep a flag like "isPlaying: true/false". By default it will be false. Once you will call play/start record pass the array index and do a simple operation array find and update.Only that passed key will be set as true and rest false as you will do looping.

Comment: But that's the problem I don't want to set multiple events as true there should be one event that could be true. If I call startRecord on two events then there will two events in true state