# how can i map the string that are in the object where empty string considered as empty line and each string restricted to one line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, object, mapping

```
{
"ptr0": [
    "Interviewer: Nancy Carolyn Camp Foster (NF)",
    "",
    "Interviewee: Edith Mills (EM)",
    "",
    "NF: Well it's kind of interesting to observe how students have turned out who've",
    "gone through Bristow schools. We lose track, we don't really realize and",
    "",
    "Other Persons: Lucy Mae Mills (LM) Unknown Woman (WS)"
        ]
}
```

I am trying to map the above objecttrans object ptr0 in jsx in browser where i want empty string in object to be considered as a empty line and each string in an object restricted to one line, something like this i am trying to show in browser jsx:

Interviewer: Nancy Carolyn Camp Foster (NF)

Interviewee: Edith Mills (EM)

NF: Well it's kind of interesting to observe how students have turned out who've
gone through Bristow schools. We lose track, we don't really realize and

Other Persons: Lucy Mae Mills (LM) Unknown Woman (WS)

Component where I am calling the Transcript Component

```
<Transcript
                transcript={objecttrans.ptr0.map(pt=>{          
                return   pt               
        })}
        />
```

Transcript Component

```
return (
    <>
      <div className="content">
           <p>{props.transcript}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render an array of objects in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41374572/how-to-render-an-array-of-objects-in-react)

Comment: I have tried but that solution is not working for me.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, because i believe it should fix the issue.

Comment: In that example, there is only one value of the key while in my case there is only one key and many values of that key, i am confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be doing what you want it to do. If your issue was that new lines are not being shown, you can just return a `br` element when the string is empty. Something like:

`objecttrans.ptr0.map(pt => pt || <br />`

```js
const Transcript = props => <div className="content">
  <p>{props.transcript}</p>
</div>;


const objecttrans = {
  "ptr0": [
    "Interviewer: Nancy Carolyn Camp Foster (NF)",
    "",
    "Interviewee: Edith Mills (EM)",
    "",
    "NF: Well it's kind of interesting to observe how students have turned out who've",
    "gone through Bristow schools. We lose track, we don't really realize and",
    "",
    "Other Persons: Lucy Mae Mills (LM) Unknown Woman (WS)"
  ]
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Transcript
    transcript={objecttrans.ptr0.map(pt => pt || <br />)}
  />, document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the array of lines into a single string using newlines:

```
const text = lines.join('\n');
```

Then put the text into a [preformatted text element `<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) instead of a [paragraph element `<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) and style however you'd like.

```js
const lines = [
  "Interviewer: Nancy Carolyn Camp Foster (NF)",
  "",
  "Interviewee: Edith Mills (EM)",
  "",
  "NF: Well it's kind of interesting to observe how students have turned out who've",
  "gone through Bristow schools. We lose track, we don't really realize and",
  "",
  "Other Persons: Lucy Mae Mills (LM) Unknown Woman (WS)",
];

const text = lines.join('\n');

document.querySelector('pre').textContent = text;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```