# Use object to map color to component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a reusable tag component and based on company will apply the correct background and text color.

```
const colorMapping = {
  facebook: "white"
}

const backgroundMapping = {
  facebook: "blue"
}

export const App = (props) => {
   return (
       <div style={{ backgroundColor: "", color: "" }}>
       {props.company} //Facebook
       </div>
   )
}
```

How can I apply the color based on the based string? and Is this the right approach, could I just use 1 mapping object?

Comment: In general it is better to create `brands` array and put inside `facebook` object (with `color` and `background` properties) ==> Otherwise it is very hard to handle data.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41374572/how-to-render-an-array-of-objects-in-react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How can I apply the color based on the based string?**
let say this.props.company name is the base string,right? if its so then you can do something like this

```
style={{ backgroundColor: backgroundMapping[this.props.company], color: colorMapping[this.props.company] }}
```

but,wait

**Is this the right approach, could I just use 1 mapping object?**
no,then why?what if there is no color for given this.props.company? so you code may need to check first that for given company name mapping found,and of course you should use single mapping instead of two,
then how?
consider the steps
create a theme object like this

```
const theme={
       facebook:{color:"while",background:"blue"},
       defaultTheme:{
            color:"while",background:"black"
        }
 }
```

and then you can assign this theme to your component as following

```
 <div style={theme[this.props.company]||theme.default}>
   {props.company} //Facebook
   </div>
```