# How can i list data from table in the database in a browser

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, localhost

I'm developing a web application using reactjs nodejs and mysql database.

I want to list the data created in a table i created in   the database in the browser via a link(http://localhost:5000/api/v/companies) .What code should i write in a page created in reactsjs?
Here is the code in the file index.js the backend of the table i created :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const pe = require('parse-error');
const logger = require('morgan');
const database = require('./mysql');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
    limit: '800mb'
}));

// CORS
app.options("*", cors());
app.use(cors());

database.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("==> MySQL Connected Successfully!");

    // The main page
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.json({
            version: 'v1',
            status: true
        });
    });

    const stations = require('./routes/stations');
    const companies = require('./routes/companies');

    app.use('/api/v1', [stations, companies]);
});
app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port 5000");
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
    console.error('Uncaught Error', pe(error));
});
```

as well as other files created in the backend

```
const database = require('./../mysql');

/**
 * List all companies
 */
const getAllCompanies = async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    database.query('SELECT * FROM infos_stations.Companies', function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;

      return res.status(200).json(result);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send({
      code: 500,
      status: false,
      data: "Internal Server Error"
    });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  getAllCompanies,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

- In the reactjs application, you have to install any library for HTTP
  requests. Axios is a Javascript library used to make HTTP requests
  from node.js or XMLHttpRequests from the browser that also supports
  the ES6 Promise.
- In the backend, You have to create a route that accepts the HTTP request from
  Frontend.

  ```
   app.post('/getdata', function (req, res) {



     // database queries etc.
     //sending response(database result)at frontend.



  }
  ```
- In reactjs you can create an HTTP request on a button click or can create a
  request on component renders using the `UseEffect` hook.

  ```
  axios({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'htttp//localhost/getdata',
     responseType: 'stream'
   })
     .then(function (response) {
                  // response.data have all data of database.
      //store response data in any reactjs state.
     });
  ```
- Use Map Function of state array in which you store a response that contains all database records. How to map lists [How to render an array of objects in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41374572/how-to-render-an-array-of-objects-in-react)